# & vs && -- how can the first case be used?

Tags: java, operators, semantics

> (a > b) & (c < d), the components are evaluated left to right, so (a >
>   b) is evaluated first. If (a > b) is false, the entire expression is
>   false regardless of the result of the component (r < d). Nevertheless,
>   the component (c < d) will still be evaluated. However, in the
>   expression (a > b) && (c < d), the component (c < d) will not be
>   evaluated if (a > b) evaluates to false. This is known as short
>   circuiting.

Came across this paragraph in a Java book. I have been programming in various languages before, but I've never found a need for '&'. Why would one want to evaluate the second statement if it's known that the end result is not affected by it? Is there any use for it; does it come due to historical reasons?

Same question applies to | and || as well.

Comment: Who are `e` and `r`? Do you have a really badly misprinted book, or is this typed from memory?

Comment: I suggest you throw out that book, it is filling your mind with garbage.  As others here will tell you, the difference between `&` and `&&` is *not* evaluation order, and using `&` with Boolean expressions like `(a > b)` doesn't make sense.

Comment: "Java Practical Guide for Programmers" M.Sikora, http://www.amazon.com/Java-Practical-Guide-Programmers-Guides/dp/1558609091 Page 26. Straight out of the book.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difference between '&' and '&&' is not well-known and that example from the book doesn't help much.

Here's another example to show how short-circuiting work (using horrible methods having side-effects, but that's not the point).

Imagine you have this:

```
private int cnt;

private boolean a() {
    cnt++;
    return false;
}

private boolean b() {
    cnt++;
    return false;
}
```

If you execute the following:

```
    cnt = 0;
    if ( a() && b() ) {}
    System.out.println( cnt );
```

It shall print 1.

While if you execute the following:

```
    cnt = 0;
    if ( a() & b() ) {}
    System.out.println( cnt );
```

It shall print 2. Because in the latter case *b()* **must** be evaluated as per the language specs while in the first case *b()* **must not** be evaluated, as per the language specs.

Comment: And +1 to "ratchet freak"'s answer giving an example as to when you may want to use such constructs.

Answer (score 2):

The [&& operator](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/expressions.html#15.23) is defined by the Java Language Specification to perform short-circuit evaluation.

However, the & operator is not, [even when applied to boolean arguments](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/expressions.html#15.22.2).

You could exploit this if one of the arguments had side-effects that you did not want short-circuited. However, in my experience this is uncommon, and you'd face the risk of someone "fixing" it. It would be better separated into steps. For example, instead of:

```
if ( foo() & bar() ) {... }
```

you could say:

```
boolean isFoo = foo();
boolean isBar = bar();
if ( isFoo && isBar ) { ... }
```

Answer (score 2):

if you expect your code to be under attack from [timing attacks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Timing_attack) you want the least amount of branches (conditional execution paths) possible, this is one way to eliminate them

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps the 2nd evaluation is in the form of an assignment statement or method call, in which case you might want it to execute. I wouldn't use bitwise operators in place of logical operators like this tho. If you need something to execute passed `&&`, then do it prior to your logical statement and store the result in a variable.

Answer (score 1):

```
if(0 != ((a > b) ? 1 : 0) & ((c < d) ? 1 : 0)) {
   // but really... (a > b) && (c < d), assuming no side-effects
}
```

**...just use the [logical operators](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logical_operator) (`&&` and `||`) for conditions ;-)** That is what they were *designed for*. If non-shortcircuit behavior is required, then restructure the code accordingly.

I think I have seen one case that had a somewhat valid use of `&` in this context, but I do not recall what it was so I mustn't have found it that valid ;-) In languages like C/C++ where there is no discreet "boolean" type, the (input) and result of `&` can be treated such that `0 -> false` and `non-0 -> true`. As can be seen, however, Java has to jump through some fun to get `bool -> int -> bool`.

The only justification for a [bit-wise operator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation) is, well, bit-wise operations, IMOHO. Bit-wise operators are most useful when performing some sort of encoding including "bit fields" and "bit masks". They are also useful when dealing with fun arising from Java's signed-only bytes, etc.

**I think the bigger (only?) point to take away is that *`&&` and `||` are short-circuiting* -- they are actually the *only operators* with this behavior** (arguments over `?:` excluded); the rest is just to explain the eager-behavior of bit-wise operators. This just goes to re-enforce the rule: *do not cause side-effects in conditionals* (outside of a few well-accepted idioms, but even then, keep it simple).

Happy coding.

---

Examples of bit-wise usage:

Imagine the use of flags which are stored into a single "integer" slot in a serialized format:

```
int flags = 0;
if (this.encypted) {
   flags |= EncryptedMode;
}
out.write(flags);

// later on
int flags = in.readInt();
this.encrypted = (flags & EncryptedMode) != 0;
```

Reading the "unsigned value" of a byte:

```
byte[] data = {-42, ...}; // read in from file or something
int unsignedByte = data[0] & 0xFF;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `&` in situations where you *have to* evaluate both subexpressions.  For example, if they both have side effects that are observable by the rest of your application.

Answer (score 0):

Your book is confusing things. For the most part, you will only use '&&' and '||'. The single ones, '&' and '|', are bitwise operators - you can read more about them here: http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/op3.html

Comment: & and | are legal boolean logical operators as well, though uncommon. You can read about them here: http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/expressions.html#15.22.2 .

Answer (score 0):

The use of a non-short-circuit operator may speed up performance-critical code by avoiding branch mis-prediction stalls, which could easily amount to a dozen or more clock cycles.